# python: close a file descriptor not assigned to any variable

Tags: python, file-descriptor

What happens to a file descriptor when I don't assign it to a variable, but I just open it "in line"? How do I close it later?

For instance:

```
import csv
writer = csv.writer(open('a_file', 'wb'))
for line in some_data:
    writer.writerow(line)
```

I know I should use `with`, but what can I do in this particular case to close the file descriptor corresponding to `a_file`?

Comment: It isn't merely "easier" to use `with`. I have absolutely no idea why you may wish to do it like so, but I strongly discourage.

Comment: Ok ok, I just wanted to know what happened in this particular case :)

Comment: There are plenty of examples on the Internet opening a file the way I described it, so I simply wondered what happened to such files descriptors. No need to get all grumpy because it's not the best and recommended way of doing this simple task. ;)

Comment: Not getting grumpy and encourage being inquisitive, just wanted to make sure ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually is garbaged collected.

It is not a good practice to do this, because you may need to flush the contents of a file to be actually written to disk. By letting the garbage collector do its job when it wants, you're not sure when or whether the file will be actually written.

Answer (score 1):

A file descriptor is like any other object in Python. When a reference to it goes out of scope, the reference count is decremented. When there are no more references to it, it is deleted.

Comment: Ok, so when I am in interactive mode it is very bad practice to do what I described!